# How to export a large collection of pcAnywhere remote connections to another format?

Tags: remote-desktop, export, pcanywhere

We have a collection of thousands of pcAnywhere connection files (.CHF) that we've been storing on a shared network drive, and I'm trying to import all the connections into [Remote Desktop Manager](http://www.remotedesktopmanager.com) in an attempt to make them easier to manage.

Remote Desktop Manager keeps track of pcAnywhere connections by storing the path of a CHF file, with an optional field for "Host override".  I plan to have a single CHF file for all our connections, then use the "Host override" to store each connection's IP address.

Remote Desktop Manager has a well-defined XML format for importing connections, but my problem is getting all the pcAnywhere file names and IP addresses into a more readable format.  The CHF files are opaque binary files, and even looking inside them with a hex editor shows no obvious way of extracting the IP address.  The pcAnywhere program itself seems to have no export mechanism.

Is there any way I can create a text, CSV, XML, or other readable file that contains the filename and IP address/phone number for all of our connections?

Comment: What happens when you open a chf file in a text editor?

Comment: "The CHF files are opaque binary files".  They are just garbage if you look at them with a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [Perl script, pcainfo.p](http://unixwiz.net/tools/pcainfo.html), which does some decoding of CHF and CIF files. It doesn't decode everything, but it got enough for my purposes.